# Does sqlite3 table size affect performance?

Tags: database, utf-8, sqlite, case

I am using sqlite3 for a database.  The database has a table which uses a "name" field as the index, which is an UTF-8 string.  In order to do case insensitive comparison, I added a new column called "name_upper", which is just the UTF-8 upper case version of the "name" field, and uses that as the index instead.

It turns out that the "name" field is by far the largest field in the table, so by defining a "name_upper" field, I have basically doubled the size of the table.  The size of the database would still be small comparing to the disk size where the database file resides, but it could become big comparing to the memory size.

My question is, does doubling the size of the table affect performance?  I am concerned that more memory would need to be used to cache the table.

An alternative solution would be to define a new collation function that performs case insensitive UTF-8 comparison (and I am aware that ICU provides an implementation).  I am not sure what would be the performance impact in that case, since every comparison would need to do the conversion from lower case to upper case.

Comment: `name_upper` is just redundant! Why don't you just make a case insensitive comparison instead of adding a new column? Regarding SQLite performance, here are the benchmark reports(They are ancient but you get an idea) http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html. If `name` is the only index you have for your table, you might want to consider having some `int` column for an index.

Answer (score 0):

Doubling the size of the table will affect performance *if* your queries actually read all the table; performance stays the same if the search can be answered by checking the index alone.

Typically, I/O dominates the runtime.
And even if your data fits into the cache, the runtime of your collation function is not likely to be noticeable because most lookups using an index use binary search, i.e., only a few records are compared.